# How to get PrismJS to highlight code block in angular directive without having to implement a 1 second timeout delay?

Tags: angular, prismjs

I have created a simple application (angular 1.6) that allows a user to save there code and have it display with code highlighting leveraging prismjs. The only problem is, when I call Prism.highlightAll from within the directive, I have to utilize angular's $timeout method with a one second delay.

```
app.directive("markupPanels", function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "directives/markupPanel.html",
    link: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            Prism.highlightAll();
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

[Code highlighted with 1 second delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WUYP.png)

The browser flickers however, and I think there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.ready()`.

```
link: function($scope, element) {
    element.ready(function() {
        Prism.highlightElement(element[0]);
    });
}
```

Source: [angular-prism](https://github.com/sercaneraslan/angular-prism-directive/blob/master/ng-prism.js).